# change logo in liferay portal

Tags: java, dom, liferay, freemarker, portal

I'm customizing my liferay theme for my own portal, I'm copy portal_normal.ftl to _diffs/templates and I saw this code :

```
<a class="${logo_css_class}" href="${site_default_url}" title="<@liferay.language key="go-to" /> ${site_name}">
    <img alt="${logo_description}" height="${site_logo_height}" src="${site_logo}" width="${site_logo_width}" />
</a>
```

I wonder that what is these ${logo_css_class}, ${site_default_url},${site_name},${logo_description} ? If it an attribute so where we will define it, and especial src="${site_logo}", is it a image url ? and how to define this attribute ?

I want to change the src from ${site_logo} to a direct url like "it.tdt.edu.vn/wp-content/themes/cs_tdt/images/…; but it does work, so how do i change the picture in logo ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the logo in liferay from Control Panel: PORTAL SETTINGS- display settings

You asked me to change the portal-normal. So you could try something like that:
init_custom.vm include: #set ($company_logo_src = "$images_folder/yourlogo.png")           portal_normal.vm change tag img: src="$company_logo_src"

$images_folder is going to take the logo from folder images (of your theme)

Comment: I would like to change in portal_normal.ftl, can you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in init.ftl in your case. You can use that or you can hard code it there itself or in the init.ftl too. They are just variables

Comment: first, I would like to thanks for your answer, may I ask you one more question ?
I want to change the src from ${site_logo} to a direct url like "http://it.tdt.edu.vn/wp-content/themes/cs_tdt/images/bg-header.png" but it does work, so how do i change the picture in logo

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 7, go to Control Panel, select the specific site. Within the site, click on the three dot for the right side of Navigation > Public Pages. Click on 'Configure' menu button. The Logo option will be at the 'Look and Feel' tab. Here you can upload a new logo image.

You can also change the logo image of a theme as mentioned in the blog post
[Overwrite Liferay Logo in Theme](https://web.liferay.com/web/bradley.wood/blog/-/blogs/overwrite-liferay-logo-in-theme)